# Understanding FHIR composite code-value-quantity queries

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

Having trouble understanding why my composite query for patient (synthetic data) with identifier 37b847a5-7e5b-439e-9adf-c325f0c837c8 on the HAPI FHIR server is yielding different results.

Using **code-value-quantity** `https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation?code-value-quantity=http://loinc.org|6298-4$lt3.0` I can find a potassium observation less than 3.0.

However, this entry is absent when retrieving observations for the patient using **Patient.identifier** `https://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/Observation?subject:Patient.identifier=37b847a5-7e5b-439e-9adf-c325f0c837c8` and only two observations greater than 3.0 are retrieved.

Really confused as to what's going on here!

[image: Retrieved JSON]

I expected that retrieving observations using Patient.identifier should return all of the observations for that patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I execute the 'patient' query, I get the first 20 Observations as well as the 'next' link.  Have you navigated through all of the 'next' links to receive all of the pages rather than just the first page?

Comment: No I hadn't! That clears it up, thank you!